# How to modify string to a character value in which each character of the string is separated by a comma?

Tags: sas

I came across this question today morning and I am still trying to figure out it can be done. the following dataset is present and has a character variable CAT.

**CAT**
A
AB
B
ABCD
CB
.
.
.
and so on.

We need to write a SAS program to introduce commas in-between each character of the string if the length of the string is more than 1. I used length() function and used a do loop to create different variables and it just got messy. How do i tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression solution:

```
data have;
input CAT $;
datalines;
A
AB
B
ABCD
CB
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
cat_c = prxchange('s/(?<=[[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]])/,$1/io',-1,CAT);
put cat_c=;
run;
```

The first parenthetical group is a look-behind for an alpha character; then the captured alpha character.  Then replace with comma and character.  If you want something other than [[:alpha:]] (ie, A-Z) then supply that as a class.

The solution using length and do loop isn't bad, honestly, if you want something that is more readable to novice programmers.  Just use SUBSTR left of the equal sign.

```
data want2;
set have;
if length(cat) > 1 then 
  do _t = 1 to length(cat)-1;
    substr(cat_c,2*_t-1,2)=substr(cat,_t,1)||',';
  end;
substr(cat_c,2*length(cat)-1,1)=substr(cat,length(cat),1);
put cat_c=;
run;
```